# Delegation from a nested navigation stack

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have standard view controller acting as the delegate for a modal view controller over it.
This modal view controller is contained in a navigation controller.

After presenting the modal, and pushing another view controller onto the navigation stack, I want to pass some data back to the initial delegate view controller (that presented the modal).

Should I pass the message back up the navigation stack to the root view controller of the modal navigation controller first, and just use the delegate methods of that controller?

OR

Should I just pass the delegate property along to the nested view controller and then call the delegate directly with a separate protocol implemented.  It work doing this, but I have to use

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;
```

instead of

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <NestedViewDelegate> delegate;
```

otherwise I get an incompatible type error when I pass the delegate from the preview view controller in the stack:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
NestedViewController *nest = [[NestedViewController alloc] init];

// @property id <RootViewControllerDelegate> delegate
[nest setDelegate:[self delegate]];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:nest animated:YES];
```

}

What is the best practice for this kind of scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Cameron, were you successful in implementing a solution? How did you solve this problem? I'm looking for a solution because I have this same problem.

Comment: I think notifications is easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using notifications to decouple this. Checkout NSNoticiationCenter.

You register for a notification in your root and publish in you child.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**EXAMPLE**

In your Child object you do something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kMyNotificationName object:self userInfo:@{ @"key" : @"value" }]];
```

`kMyNotificationName` is defined in a shared place, like the pch or a Constants.h.

In the Root you would do something like this, either in `init` or perhaps whenever you push the child.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myNotificationName:) name:kMyNotificationName object:nil];
```

*Don't forget to remove observers in your dealloc or when you pop the child.*

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self kMyNotificationName object:nil];
```

Now you can handle the notification something like this:

```
- (void)myNotificationName:(NSNotification *)note
{
     NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];

     // Do stuff using the information passed in.
}
```

Comment: Hey Cameron, were you successful in implementing this solution? How did you solve this problem? I'm looking for a solution because I have this same problem.

Comment: For learning about changes in view controllers deep in a navigation stack, using delegation and chaining it back up is cumbersome. I highly recommend using notifications.

Comment: @logancautrell Hi, can you edit your post for a snippet of code on how to register that notification and publish it in child please? I am running into the same issue :(

Comment: Sure, gimme a few minutes :D